# Compiling a file in Dockerfile and moving it to a different directory (Docker)

Tags: image, docker, makefile, directory, dockerfile

I want to compile a makefile, and move the resulting compiled file into another directory. For example if I am in the directory:

```
WORKDIR /Directory1/
```

And after:

```
RUN make
```

Which should produce a compiled file named "abc". I want to then move this file to another directory, which we'll called "Directory2". This is what I tried but it did not work:

```
COPY /Directory1/abc/ /Directory2/
```

Any advice?

Comment: First, you should always say exactly what happened (what messages or error you received etc.) rather than saying "it did not work".  That doesn't help anyone help you.  Second, do you have a slash at the end of your filename, like `/Directory1/abc/`?  If so, why?  That will cause commands to assume that `abc` is a directory, not a file.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Docker and stackoverflow. I will make sure to do that for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker has a concept of [Layers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#images-and-layers).

Within a dockerfile, each command executes and creates a different layer, hence the layer generated by your make command is not accessible by the other layers.

To make it work use the make and copy commands in a single Run. e.g.

```
RUN cd /Directory1/ && make && cp abc /Directory2/
```

Comment: (This will work just fine even if you `RUN cp` in a separate command producing a separate layer.)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.